# What will be the default return type of knex in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following function and i cant seem to figure out its return type

```
export function save(contractType: ContractType, tx?: Knex.Transaction): any {
  return db
    .connection(tx)(CONTRACT_TYPE_TABLE)
    .insert(contractType)
    .catch(err => {
      throw new DatabaseError(en.GENERIC_ERROR, err);
    });
}
```

Comment: It'll be the type of whatever `db.connection().insert()` returns

Comment: connection returns Knex and insert returns Array<t>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the type definitions available on GitHub, I assume that you are working with a `QueryBuilder` instance.

```
interface QueryBuilder extends QueryInterface, ChainableInterface
```

this means that your Insert method get called on something that implements the `QueryInterface` and the `ChainableInterfaces` interfaces.

`Insert` is defined in the `QueryInterface` interface and returns the `QueryBuilder` it has been called on. Not much of an info.

Looking at the `ChainableInterface` instead we notice that it extends `BlueBird<any>`.

```
interface ChainableInterface extends Bluebird<any>
```

Bluebird is one of the many JavaScript promise libraries. You can read more about it [here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html)

So, summing all we know so far...

> Insert returns `Bluebird<any>`

Looking at the Bluebird library, it seems `Catch` returns the promise object it has been called on (as expected from a promise library). This means that your method actually return a `Bluebird<any>` promise

As for the actual type... based on the samples available in the Knex documentation, `Insert` should be returning an array with the indexes of the inserted records. So, it should be safe enough to assume that you are working with a promise that returns a number array.

In conclusion:

Your method is returning a `QueryBuilder` object that may be used to build more queries (that should be the purpose of the `ChainableInterface`). It *should* also work as a `Bluebird<number[]>` promise that you can use to get the inserted records identifiers if needed.

Comment: thank you for the reply but i get "Argument of type '(Bluebird<number[]> | QueryBuilder[])[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<number[] | PromiseLike<number[]>>'."  error while i do promise.all  . I tried wrapping the arrray for promise.all as https://devhints.io/bluebird but all my promises dont resolve now.

Comment: @Pradipshrestha I fear this may be due to [this issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/11027) relating to the Bluebird library. It seems that due to some issues/design choices in the library, currently the Bluebird promise is not directly assignable to a ES6 promise. Will try and see if I can think of any better solution, in the meantime I fear your best option is to see if any of the proposed workaround in the linked github discussion could be of any help in your case.